# Android how do you reference a newer Class from the Lollipop RippleDrawable

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, rippledrawable

I have a method to create RippleDrawables in code

```
    public class StateApplier {    

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        private static void add_Ripple(Resources res, StateListDrawable states
                , int color, int pressedColor){
            Drawable rd = new android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable(get_Ripple_ColorSelector(pressedColor)
                    , new ColorDrawable(color), null);
            states.addState(new int[] {}, rd);

        }
```

Which works fine when I run it on a Lollipop, but when I run it on KitKat device, it crashes. Here is the error log.

```
03-12 21:36:47.734: E/dalvikvm(26295): Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method com.acme.applib.Render.StateApplier.add_Ripple
03-12 21:36:47.734: W/dalvikvm(26295): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 149 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Lcom/acme/applib/Render/StateApplier;
03-12 21:36:47.734: D/dalvikvm(26295): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
03-12 21:36:47.738: W/dalvikvm(26295): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;)
03-12 21:36:47.738: W/dalvikvm(26295): VFY: returning Ljava/lang/Object; (cl=0x0), declared Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable; (cl=0x0)
03-12 21:36:47.738: W/dalvikvm(26295): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x11 at 0x0004
03-12 21:36:47.738: W/dalvikvm(26295): VFY:  rejected Lcom/acme/applib/Render/StateApplier;.create_Ripple (Landroid/content/res/Resources;II)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-12 21:36:47.738: W/dalvikvm(26295): Verifier rejected class Lcom/acme/applib/Render/StateApplier;
```

I thought using  **@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)** would force the the code to be skipped on devices lower than a lollipop. What's strange it that is crashing on activity that does not even call the method add_Ripple() but calls another method in the StateApplier class.

Note I am also using an api check before calling the method

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
add_Ripple(res, states, color, pressedColor);
```

What would be the appropriate way of referencing classes in newer APIs without it crashing on older devices.

Comment: "I thought using @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) would force the the code to be skipped on devices lower than a lollipop." No, you have to actually add code to skip it, e.g. `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) { ... }`

Comment: That is a conditional statement on whether to run the code and that I am already using. But  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION...  should prevent the compilation errors, by  having the compiler Skip these code segments when compiling.

Comment: No, that's not what that annotation does at all. It just tells the linter that it shouldn't warn about API level within the annotated method. Check the javadocs for [TargetApi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi.html).

Comment: I have posted a solution which I used below as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was create another class called **StateApplierLollipop** and moved
all code dealing with **RippleDrawable** there, and the code in StateApplier will only call that code in StateApplierLollipop for Lollipop+ devices. This stopped the crashes on KitKat.

```
public class StateApplierLollipop {  
public static void add_Ripple(Resources res, StateListDrawable states
                , int color, int pressedColor){
    ...........
   }
}

public class StateApplier{
public static void add_Ripple(Resources res, StateListDrawable states
                    , int color, int pressedColor){
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
   StateApplierLollipop.add_Ripple(....
```

}